# Can I take a svn dump and reparent a directory?

Tags: svn, dump, svnadmin

I am moving SVN providers, and in doing so all of my repos start like `https://www.provider1.com/myrepo1` so I've done a svn dump on that repo, and within the repo my paths start `trunk/src`, `trunk/lib`, etc.  However, my new provider gives me only a single URL for me to dump my projects into those.  So I need to rename all of the directories in the dump to add a new parent to each path so it might look like `myrepo1/trunk/src`, `myrepo1/trunk/lib`, etc.  I realize I can create a new directory in each URL repo, and move the folders into it.  But that doesn't change the history of it.  So is there a way to use svndumpfilter to add this parent into the dump file directly?  If not what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did to get it to work.  I didn't use svndumpfilter after all.  Instead I created a new repository using `svnadmin` then created a parent directory in that newly created svn repo.  Then loaded the dump using `svnadmin load` telling it to put that dump under the new parent directory.

First pull down the project and create a dump of that project:

```
svnadmin create project1
emacs repo/hooks/pre-revprop-change
chmod 755 project1/hooks/pre-revprop-change
svnsync init file://$(pwd)/project1 https://somehost.com/svn/project1
svnsync sync file://$(pwd)/project1
svnadmin dump project1 > some.dump
```

Next create a new svn project for which we'll load the dump into the new parent directory:

```
svnadmin create someDirectory
svn mkdir -m "Add root directory to project" file://$(pwd)/someDirectory/THE_PARENT_NAME
cat some.dump | svnadmin load --parent-dir THE_PARENT_NAME someDirectory
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you may use [svnkitfilter](https://sourceforge.net/projects/svnkitfilter/) based on [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com):

```
$ svnkitfilter OLD_ROOT_URL NEW_URL --prefix myrepo1
```